# Error invoking COM from managed DLL via NUnit

Tags: nunit

I have a unit test case, written in C#, wherein I have to invoke a COM object. The test case works fine, when run stand alone. The same when tried via NUnit (v-2.5.9), it fails with following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Could not convert argument 0 for call to StartInstall.
   at System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo,     UInt32 argErr, String message)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject , String , String , String , Object )
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String , String , String , Object )
```

Any clues on this weird behavior?